# Блок fixed смещается на мобильниках

Tags: css, css3

Как пофиксить **смещение подвала вправо и вниз** с классом .page-footer и **position:fixed** на мобильных при открытии popup.

```
.popup {
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 640px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      &--off {
        transform: scale(0);
      }
      &__wrapper {
        width: 320px;
        padding: 21px 10px 20px;
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
        z-index: 100;
      }
}



.page-footer {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 64px;
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
      z-index: 200;
      &__wrapper {
        width: 320px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы футер растянуть на мобилках, для `page-footer__wrapper` задайте свойству `width` значение в `100%` на нужном разрешении. По поводу остального, лучше загрузите код в какую-либо песочницу, а то сейчас трудно сказать, что там не так.

Comment: @Марсель  У меня было width: 100%,поэтому как только ширина page-footer увеличивалась,то и центровка была посередине,отсюда и margin слева...